# How to make Entity Framework DB-first generate single .cs file instead of one file per class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've an existing database with many (~500) tables and stored procedures. Whenever the database gets updated, I need to re-generate the .edmx file for Entity Framework 6 based on the new schema; the process produces about 500 files, one per each table and at least one per each stored procedure that returns results.

For various reasons, I'd rather have a single file with all classes in it.

I know I can comment out this line `<EntityModelName>.tt` to consolidate all files:

```
// fileManager.Process()
```

However I can do this only *after* Entity Framework generated 500+ files. Having to do this every few days gets quite annoying.

Updating the .edmx file instead of deleting and re-generating it often results in errors due to DB schema issues that won't be resolved anytime soon.

What would be the best way ensure that only one .cs file generated from the outset?  I am willing to go as far as forking EntityFramework, modifying VS templates, or doing other unconventional things as necessary.

Comment: Can you use code first instead of edmx file, you can generate all your POCOs in single file and work as database first by setting the context initializer to null.

Comment: @Omar.Alani I'm working with existing large DB, so going code-first is considerably more labor-intensive than going with DB-first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838) tool which you can configure to generate all your POCOs into a single file (by default) or to separate files, also it has more options can you look at and check through the video exists on the link that I've mentioned.

Remember that you can switch between code-first and database first by just setting the context's initializer to null, so something like :

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    static MyDbContext()
    {
        // I don't want to initialize my database from code, I already have a database.
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    //
    //
    // you dbsets goes here
}
```

You can find more details about initialize db contexts [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

So in a few words you can use the tool to generate the POCOs for you and still use your database, which is much cleaner than using EDMX files.

Let me know if you need more details or if you still confused.